# Examples of ontologies in artificial intelligence

Tags: artificial-intelligence, ontology

So if ontology are a description of concepts and relationships that exist of entities. Does that mean knowledge representation systems like frames and semantic nets uses them?

How do ontologies relate to practical representations. What real world examples are there?

Answer (score 1):

You are right that frames and semantic nets use (or can use) ontologies, but not only. A natural language processing system, for example, could make use of ontologies in order to decide that the word "cat" is semantically similar to "dog".

Two prominent ontologies are present in the projects [Cyc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyc) and [Ontolingua](http://www.ksl.stanford.edu/software/ontolingua/). [Wordnet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WordNet) is a lexical database but its more abstract layers can be seen as a simple ontology.